# DRF Create list of objects even when some of them not valid

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently working on a DRF project where I'm dealing with a scenario where I receive a list of objects through a POST request. The challenge I'm facing is that this list might contain some objects that are not valid according to certain criteria. However, I need to go ahead and create all the valid objects, and then perform a bulk creation of all these valid objects in one go.

I've tried a few approaches, but I'm running into issues with properly validating and handling the objects, especially when using a many=True, if one of the items are not valid than no items created at all.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation or can provide insights on how to approach this? Any guidance on how to correctly structure the validation, filtering, and bulk creation process would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Here is the code I've managed to write, but it doesn't look right to iterate over objects in the view:

```
@action(methods=['post'], detail=False, url_path='custom_method')
def custom_method(self, request):
    created = []
    for item in request.data:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=item)
        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        except ValidationError:
            # ... make log
            continue
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        created.append(serializer.data.get('id'))
    # custom action for created objects
    ...
    return Response(...)
```

Comment: When you say "bulk creation in one go", can you specify more closely what you mean?

Comment: Just `bulk_create`